# How to remove line highlight in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I just upgraded to the new version of Xcode, and it now highlights the current line of where my cursor resides. I find it annoying and would like to remove it, but I can't seem to find anything that relates to this in the settings menu. Is this possible to remove?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select **Xcode > Preferences > Fonts & Color**

[image]

Now click on `Current Line` (see the red arrow) and select the same color of the background.